# Should I say "this shows lack of progress" or "this shows a lack of progress"?

Tags: articles

I've seen both, including in reputable websites, so I don't know which is right or how, in general, decide which to use:

This shows lack of progress

This shows a lack of progress

Comment: Do you mean there has been no progress since some specified previous point, or in general?

Comment: The first might be used in _certain_ contexts - "This shows lack of progress to be endemic", for example - but the second is more common, as shown by [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shows+lack+of%2Cshows+a+lack+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshows%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshows%20a%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0).